# Unable to resolve class grails.doc.internal.StringEscapeCategory

Tags: grails, gsp

Hi,

I want to display a value in a label.
I have the following source code in gsp page :

```
<%@ page import="grails.doc.internal.StringEscapeCategory; toolprod.Portal;   toolprod.IndexController" %>
<html>
....
<%
for(String p : app?.portals) {
 if (p != null) {
   String span = StringEscapeCategory.encodeAsHtml("<span class=\"label label-info\">")
   out.print(span)
   out.print(p)
   span = StringEscapeCategory.encodeAsHtml("</span>")
   out.print(span)
 }
}
%>
```

....

I have the error unable to resolve class grails.doc.internal.StringEscapeCategory.
Does I need a plugin in BuildConfig.groovy ?
Does-it exists a better way to escape HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

More idiomatic would be to use the GSP `<g:each>` tag:

```
<g:each in="${app?.portals?.findAll()}">
  <span class="label label-info">${it}</span>
</g:each>
```

The `.findAll()` (with no argument) will filter the list to just those elements that are Groovy-true, i.e. not null, a zero number, or an empty string.